# Using rvest to scrape <a href>'s in <svg>'s

Tags: html, r, svg, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape all links on a svg map. I'm sorry I can't post the link because you'd need a login, but the html file goes like this:

```
...
<div class = 'header'>
    <div class = 'headermenu'>
    ## only other place where there exists <a href> tabs
        <a href = 'link_is_here'>...</a>
        ## four more of them, separated with non-breaking spaces
    </div>
</div>
<div class = 'main'></div>
<svg parameters_of_graphic>
    ## paths for images
    <a href='link_is_here' parameters_of_link>
        ## path for above link
    </a>
    ## paths for images
    <a href='link_is_here' parameters_of_link>
        <circle parameters_of_circle></circle>
    </a>
    ## multiple circle links of same format
</svg>
...
```

However, when I use `home_url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('a')`, I only get the five  nodes under the header class. I tried looking for svg scraping with rvest, but I couldn't find any way of scraping the  nodes under the svg tab. Is there any way to do this in R?

Answer (score -1):

I can't be sure without seeing the actual webpage, however I suspect that the svg is being generated dynamically with javascript. `read_html()` doesn't run the js on the page, and so those links might not exist when it reads the page.

You should be able to look at what `read_html()` is returning to confirm this.

Comment: That may be the case, because rvest also returns `?` instead of the real-time weather when scraping. Is there a way to let rvest run js?

Comment: Unfortunately, running the page's js is a little more complicated than `rvest` can handle. I'd suggest looking into [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html). Also [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/scraping-with-selenium/) blog post looks like it could be helpful.

Comment: Note that in that tutorial, `startServer()` function is defunct, please use `rsDriver()` instead.